# How to extract paragaphs between two strings in Python and store each paragraphn in different columns of datframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-extraction

```
Text = "This email is confidential dont share with others
From : user1@email,To: reciver1@email.com, Subject:Test1, ******emailBody*********, Regards,User1."
From : user2@email,To: reciver2@email.com, Subject:Test2, ******emailBody*********, Regards,User2.
This email is confidential dont share with others"
```

From this i need to take "From as delimter" and

append `"From : user1@email,To: reciver1@email.com, Subject:Test1, ******emailBody*********, Regards,User1.`" in one column of dataframe

and

From : user2@email,To: reciver2@email.com, Subject:Test2, ******emailBody*********, Regards,User2.
in another column of dataframe".

I tried using regex and Split methods, but failed to get Solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
strings = Text.split('From')
```

This will result in a list of the different strings
You can validate each sentence later, e.g. if 'To:' is present and if so add back the 'From:' to the beginning